# How can I invert this bit operation?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Well this is probably very easy but I'm stuck.

I'm working with a 16 bit sized *long* variable which holds the value of the current hour and minute.

```
0000 1000 0011 1111
```

### Please note:

The first 4 bits are useless;

The last 6 bits are the hours, and the remaining represents the minutes;

There is no way to change this variable type or size;

And this is how I successfully get the hours and minutes:

```
hour = ((int) original_value >> 6) & 0x1F;
minute = ( (int) original_value ) & 0x3F;
```

How can I reverse this operation to create new `original_value` with different hours and minutes?

Comment: If the last 6 bits are the hours, how come you shift right 6 bits to get the hour?

Comment: Also why do you bitwise and with `0x1F`? Shouldn't it be `0x3F` in both the cases since each are 6 bits long?

Comment: I think you mean "readling from the left .. the first 4 bits are useless ... the 'next' 6 bits are the hours and the last 6 bits are minutes".

Comment: Yes @DanAllen . Sorry it was a little confusing.

Comment: @Codebender the reason why I'm bitwising with `0x1F` it's because I want to eliminate any useless information that may come before hour and minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be missing something, but this should do the trick:

```
new_value = (new_hour << 6) | (new_minutes & 0x3f);
```

Although as others have pointed out, the way you are extracting `hour` is probably wrong, you should be `AND`ing with `0x3F`, not `0x1F`:

```
hour = ((int) original_value >> 6) & 0x3F;
```

Comment: I would add a validation that `0 <= new_minutes <=59` as bit-packing values that turn out to be out of their legal range tends to cause weird errors that can prove hard to track down. Maybe even `... | (new_minutes&0x3F)` or `0b111111` if you're Java 7 onwards.

Comment: @SeanBright Why `AND`ing with `0x3f` validates that `0 <= new_minutes <=59`? If `new_minutes=60` (which is 0x3c) , then `0x3c & 0x3f = 0x3c` and we still have an invalid value?

Comment: @TDG It is not going to validate that the hours are between 0 and 59, it is just going to stop more than 6 bits getting `OR`ed into the result. Validating the values of `new_hour` and `new_minute` are, IMO, outside of the scope of the question (and trivial to implement).